# wrap anchor tag around parent element

Tags: jquery

I have a div with anchor tag inside it. I need to wrap the entire div with anchor tag with the same href as in child div using jQuery.

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">
     <h3><a href="example.com">MORE INFORMATION</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>

Expected output:

<a href="example.com" target="_blank">
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">
     <h3><a href="example.com">MORE INFORMATION</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Invalid HTML, should not have an anchor in an anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you don't want to use `wrap` function and you want to use common `jQuery` functions:

```
;(function(p){
    $("<a target='_blank' href='"+p.find("a").attr("href")+"'></a>").insertBefore(p).append(p);
})($(".parent-div"));
```

But nested anchor is not valid. For solve this problem you can update above code similar this:

```
 ;(function(p){
    var a=p.find("a");
    $("<a target='_blank' href='"+a.attr("href")+"'></a>").insertBefore(p).append(p);
    $("span").insertBefore(a).html(a.html());
    a.remove();
  })($(".parent-div"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.wrap()` function as shown below
**[For More Information on Wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**

```js
$(function(){
  var $anchor = $('div.parent-div a').clone();//clone existing anchor
  $anchor.text('');//remove text
  $anchor.attr('target','_blank');
  $('div.parent-div').wrap($anchor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">
     <h3><a href="example.com">MORE INFORMATION</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot add the link as such in the script, because it keeps changing often. So i need to get the link as a variable and then wrap it

Comment: got it, please check my updated post where i have cloned the existing anchor and wrap it. Are ther multiple divs and anchors? if yes then you can loop it and apply same logic. let me know if you need any help

Comment: anchor in an anchor